# mssql datetimeoffset not regonized

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, parsing, datetimeoffset

I'm getting Values from my database, save them in a List, change Values and Update the database. 
No error message shows up.

The Values in the database are saved like this -> "2014-07-11 06:35:09.343 +00:00"

```
string dateformat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";

foreach (var value in vals)
{
    dt = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(value[0].ToString(),dateformat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    String sqlString = "UPDATE SampleValues " +
                       "SET Value = @VALUE " +
                       "WHERE ID = @ID AND SampleTime = @DATETIME";

    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlString, connection);

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = ID;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@DATETIME", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset).Value = dt;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@VALUE", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, int.MaxValue).Value = value[1];
    var excuter = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Nothing in the database gets updated. 
When the value is parsed dt = {11.07.2014 06:35:09 +00:00}
When I change my string dateformat to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"
I get an error. String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
I also tried CAST(@DATETIME as datetimeoffset(7)) nothing happened. 
The Datetype in the Datebase is datetimeoffset(3)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code in future. There was no reason for the body of your loop to be so massively indented.

Comment: Because `yyyy-MM-dd` format doesn't fit with your `11.07.2014` string.

Comment: From the look of the WHERE clause on the face of it, it seems unlikely to match any records, it would have to be an exact match on the id and the  sampletime fields. Are you sure there are any records that match that precisely.

Comment: I collect all my values from the exact same table and update them when the value is corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the samples you provided, you have values in the database with millisecond precision, but you are parsing values from strings with only whole second precision.

```
2014-07-11 06:35:09.343 +00:00   !=    2014-07-11 06:35:09 +00:00
```

These can't be equal because one side is 343 milliseconds difference from the other.

In general, it's not a great idea to match timestamps with such fine precision using exact equality.  Instead, consider a range match.  If you know you have values to the whole second, you could match values >= the start of the whole second and < the start of the next whole second.

Then again - it would appear you already have an ID in your where clause.  If that's indeed a unique identifier, then there's no need to match on the timestamp at all.

Comment: thanks this worked for me. The ID and the timestamp are the primary keys. I get values from sensors in certain periods. So just matching the ID would mean I lose all values ...